# Why this@MainActivity does'n work enywhere?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a ViewHolder that when a user presses a viewHolder, it have to show a Toast.(The viewHolder class is in MyAdapter class)
The first parameter of Toast.makeText method is a context. When i write this@MainActivity it get me a syntax error : unresulved refrence: @MainActivity.
but when i write it in MainActivity works good.
Please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your adapter class is inside an activity or fragment, you have to use `inner` keyword before class:

```
inner class MyAdapter {}
```

this way, if the adapter is inside your MainActivity, the this@MainActivity will work.

if it's not inside your activity, you have to get the context from Activity or fragment as parameter,

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context) {}
```

or

```
class MyAdapter(val activity: Activity) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that is not MainActivity instance, `this@MainActivity` will only work when you need a context inside `MainActivity.kt` file.

You should use `val context = holder.itemView.context` and then use `Toast.makeText(context, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: What is holder? It's an instance of my view holder?if yes how to get it? Thanks

Comment: @Amir I believe holder in this case is your ViewHolder... if you are inside your ViewHolder class then you can get it by using the `this` keyword, so `this.itemView.context`... but if you're inside the ViewHolder you can also just grab the item view directly like `val context = itemView.context`